# Deserialize Json encountered URL change

Tags: json, facebook-graph-api, url, json.net

I have an Json string return by facebook api and I want to cast it to an object, I tried using both Newton Json and JavaScriptSerializer.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/1111111111111/comments?limit=25&after=NTA\u00253D
```

After I cast it to a strongly typed object or a dynamic object, the url will be changed to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/1111111111111/comments?limit=25&after=NTA%3D
```

What is the cause of this issue?

I have tried url encoding and decoding, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JSON, any character can be represented by a unicode escape sequence, which is defined as `\u` followed by 4 hexadecimal digits (see [JSON.org](http://www.json.org/)).  When you deserialize the JSON, each escape sequence is replaced by the actual unicode character.  You can see this for yourself if you run the following example program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"{ ""Test"" : ""\u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f"" }";
        Foo foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json);
        Console.WriteLine(foo.Test);
    }
}

class Foo
{
    public string Test { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
Hello
```

In your example URL, `\u0025` represents the `%` character.  So the two URLs are actually equivalent.  There is no issue here.