# Exception while converting String to Double C#

Tags: c#, parsing, double

I take data from four different pages and different domains.

1- .com

2- .co.uk

3- .ca

4- .co.jp

For all of the above i take number from Html and Convert them to Double using line:

```
string  lowestSellerPrice = (Convert.ToDouble(fbalPrice) + 
                             Convert.ToDouble(fbalsPrice)).ToString();
```

This works perfectly fine for the first 3 domains but for .co.jp even though there is always a number in `fbalPrice` and `fbalsPrice` it is always giving exception :

```
Input string was not in a correct format
```

Any suggestion as i have been struggling with this for too long now no result i also tried the `try parse` solution but no luck.

**UPDATE:**

See this:

[image]

Comment: " even though there is always a number in fbalPrice and fbalsPrice" , are you sure there is nothing else than numbers in your string ? Use a debugger, see what exactly is the value of `fbalPrice`

Comment: What is the exact content of `fbalPrice` and `fbalsPrice` when it throws the error?

Comment: 2400 and 1200 that is what is the issue always a number...also to mention in case of .co.jp when i reach this line even if i manually put the numbers in there to check if there is something different with number in japanese maybe still i get the error so no matter what i do i get the exception

Comment: Forget not, the hidden invisible character... I mean, you're talking about .jp, what are the odds of having an unknown invisible japanese character in your console output? HUGE

Comment: Just try `string fbalPrice = "2400"; double d = Convert.ToDouble(fbalPrice);`, This would never throw the exception, Put a debug point, examine `fbalPrice` and `fbalsPrice` values.

Comment: @RobEpstein Read the question he already said that he has tried TryParse...

Comment: @Habib tried everything thing yes i think that might be the case as there is a space at the end i used Trim() it wont end so i manually did Replace(" ","") and it works but the time it reaches that line there is always only number still exception

Comment: Have you tried using the japanese culture with `Double.TryParse` as in `double.TryParse(fbalPrice, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ja-JP"))`?

Comment: @DanielJ.G. havent tried that let me check.

Comment: Btw why a downvote what is wrong with my question?

Comment: There may be a non-printable character in there, as in [this case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25403588/jsonserializer-deserialize-not-working-properly-for-unicode-characters-in-c-shar/25403869#comment39625289_25403869). Ensure the text contains only numeric characters with a Regex

Comment: @DanielJ.G. just tried it changes everything to 0.0 no exception though.

Comment: updated the question for all to see the values , so you can see there is only number

Comment: That `jp` looks suspicions. Do they (Japanese guys) use *digits* to represent numbers? Try to use [`double.Parse(fbalPrice, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9ebt447.aspx).

Comment: @Sinatr same exception ....

Comment: Okz i solved it , looks stupid actually...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this :

The string were like " 1234" and " 111" and i then did Replace(" ",""); . And only number lift this however did not work so i did this:

```
 if (fbalPrice.Contains(" "))
     {
     fbalPrice = fbalPrice.Remove(0, fbalPrice.IndexOf(" ") + 1).Replace(",","").Trim();
     }
 if(fbalsPrice.Contains(" "))
     {
     fbalsPrice = fbalsPrice.Remove(0, fbalsPrice.IndexOf(" ") + 1).Replace(",", "").Trim();
     }
```

And then added them and it worked.